# how to sort javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, json

Here are my objects:

```
var user1 = new Object();
user1.username = "user1"; user1.sex="m"; user1.age=20;

var user2 = new Object();
user2.username = "user1"; user2.sex="f";user2.age=30;

var user3 = new Object();
user3.username = "user3"; user3.sex="f";user3.age=22;

var users = {"john":user1, "jerry": user2, "marry":user3};
```

How can I sort users by age ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of countless questions, use the search.

Comment: use any sort algorithm available... note however, object is not ordered.

Comment: JavaScript objects are not JSON.

Comment: Don't know your implementation but `users` should be an `array` not `object`. And then search for an algo to sort array of objects.

Comment: a) There is no JSON here, this is not JSON.  JSON is a *string representation* of data (that so happens to be based off of JavaScript syntax).  b) JavaScript objects are **unordered**.  If you need a specific order, use an array.

Comment: P.S. Use `user1 = {};` instead of `var user1 = new Object();`.  P.P.S. You can also just do `var user1 = {username: 'user1', sex: 'm', age: 20};`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Can not agree with you more.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider storing users in an array, not an object

```
var users = [user1, user2, user3];
```

then you need a sort function

```
//a and be will be passed in, you need to tell it which one is greater
function sortByAge(a,b) {

  if (a.age > b.age) return 1;
  if (a.age < b.age) return -1;
  /* else */ return 0;

  //how I had it previously that people commented on
  //return a.age > b.age;  
}
```

then you can use that sort wherever you need

```
users.sort(sortByAge);
```

Comment: [That comparison function is not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi why not?.. worked for me

Comment: Please closely read the explanation in the linked Q&A. Try out the counterexample generator…

Comment: @CharlieWynn answer to your exact question is in the accepted answer on the link :P

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  did not even realize that was a link somehow :P

Comment: @Bergi I can't even explain how long I've been doing it like that - thanks for the link!

Comment: @CharlieWynn: Thanks for the edit :-)

Comment: @CharlieWynn: Since the `age` is an int, you can actually `return a.age - b.age;` inside `sortByAge()`.  The comparison function just needs to return any positive number, any negative number, or zero.

Comment: too clever for me @RocketHazmat - thanks for editing in the .age btw

Comment: Problem is I fetch users by id ex: users["1"].age etc.. so I cannot have an array but associative array